# How to check whether the logged-in user is interactive or idle in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

In `WPF` application,  I let the user to log-in but how can i check whether the logged-in user is interactive or idle in my application?

**Interactive**: If user is using the application in every minute.

**Idle**: If user does not use application in one minute.

**Possible Solution:**
One possible solution can be that we set a timer which continuously counts the duration and saved back to database.

**But** I do not want to add an overhead of timer to my application as it already has high processing time. Further more, if user just shut down PC without loggin-out from application, the database storage part can be skipped.

Comment: Timer has very little overhead. But as far as your question goes, you need to start by defining "interactive" and "idle". These can mean a variety of things, and a timer isn't going to help unless you know exactly what events will cause you to want to reset the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer
    (
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,// Or DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle
    (s, e) => { mainWindow.Activate(); }, // or something similar
    Application.Current.Dispatcher
    );
```

Comment: Adding you more, I found a similar link ass a solution to my problem.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/811f5706-b9d7-414c-a590-cb9f6108b564/wpf-how-to-detect-application-idle?forum=wpf

Answer (score 2):

Timer is not that bad, try something like this.

You can find client Idle handler class on here : [ClientIdleHandler.cs](https://gist.github.com/IranthaJ/c06e19ab35b7ca18be4d)

```
class GetIdleTime
{
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    private ClientIdleHandler _clientIdleHandler;

    //call for idle time
    public void callForIdletime()
    {
        _clientIdleHandler = new ClientIdleHandler();
        _clientIdleHandler.Start();
        //start timer
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += TimerTick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_clientIdleHandler.IsActive)//active
        {
               //What you gonna do when idle
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What if user just shut down the PC and my code for logging time does not execute?

Comment: I think you should handle application exit event for that. you can save idle times temporally on local database (since it quick to store)